# Randomizing While Loop Game VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop

I am making a game in VB that allows the user to try and guess a number. The user should guess the number and if they too high or low then the computer will tell them. Once the user gets it right the computer will tell them how many goes it took.  I looked on this website and many others to find out how to get my while loop to work but it has confused me due to me having more than one statement.
Currently I cannot get the computer to tell the user how many goes they have done and when they try and guess the number every time it says Too high and loops that forever until I end the program.

Here is the program and thanks for any help in advance.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim usersguess, guesstime As Integer

    Randomize()

    Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((20 * Rnd()) + 1))

    Console.WriteLine("You have to guess this number.")

    usersguess = Console.ReadLine()

    While usersguess < value Then
        Console.WriteLine("You are wrong. You're to low. Go higher ")
    End While
    While usersguess > value
        Console.WriteLine("Your too high. Go Lower.")
    End While

    While usersguess = value
        Console.WriteLine("Your correct. Well Done")
    End While

    Console.WriteLine("You took,{0}", guesstime)


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there really a `While-Then` statement in VB.Net? o-o

Answer (score 4):

First, you're only asking the user for input once - the `ReadLine` needs to also be within a loop to ask for multiple guesses.  Using that single loop, you can then use `If` statements to check the answer:

```
usersguess = Console.ReadLine()
'keep looping until they get the right value
While userguess <> value
    'now check how it compares to the random value
    If usersguess < value Then
        Console.WriteLine("You are wrong. You're too low. Go higher ")
    ElseIf usersguess > value Then
        Console.WriteLine("You're too high. Go Lower.")
    End If

    'read another guess
    usersguess = Console.ReadLine()
End While

Console.WriteLine("You're correct. Well Done")
```

---

I'd also recommend turning on `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` to help weed out any errors that may creep in, in this instance it means you'll need to explicitly convert from the read text to an integer:

```
usersguess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

Note that this itself will fail if you don't enter a number... I'll leave how to deal with this properly as an exercise, but will point you towards [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that, but I also need to tell the user how many times it took them to come up with the correct answer and this is the main part on what I am stuck on

Answer (score 0):

You would just need a counter to do that.

```
    Sub Main()
     Dim intAssignedcounter As Int32 = 0
    Dim usersguess

    Randomize()

    Dim value As Integer = 8 'CInt(Int((20 * Rnd()) + 1))

    Console.WriteLine("You have to guess this number.")

    usersguess = Console.ReadLine()
    'keep looping until they get the right value
    While usersguess <> value
        'now check how it compares to the random value
        If usersguess < value Then
            intAssignedcounter += 1
            Console.WriteLine("You are wrong. You're too low. Go higher ")
        ElseIf usersguess > value Then
            Console.WriteLine("You're too high. Go Lower.")
        End If

        'read another guess
        usersguess = Console.ReadLine()


    End While
    '        Console.WriteLine("You're correct. Well Done")
    If usersguess = value Then
        Console.WriteLine("You took,{0}", intAssignedcounter)
    End If


    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I also cannot guess this too work I have tried that counter that you put in and a normal counter but It always says "You took 1" instead of how many they actually tried.